# twistlock vulnerability libx11

Tags: security

In my spring boot microservices application, I run twistlock scan to detect vulnerabilities.
Twistlock scan gave me a report that 'libx11' is having vulnerablity. I am not able to find which dependency tree is having this libx11. Any one faced same issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you creating a Docker image, it may come from some Linux dependency contains in the docker image.
libx11 is a Linux library This would be installed on the image, rather than through pom.xml. If the CVE error indicates that is with the apk format then it should would be the Alpine Linux package.